# OpenGL rendering to framebuffer with two different programs does not work correctly with NVidia GeForce RTX 2080

Tags: linux, opengl, graphics, nvidia, lwjgl

I wrote a test suite using LWJGL and Clojure to test OpenGL rendering using frame buffers.
The following program is supposed to render two quads into the frame buffer.
See [here](https://github.com/wedesoft/sfsim/blob/7111492326bfccb623a3ff5fb11323e62ff9ab18/src/sfsim/render.clj#L377) for offscreen rendering implementation.

```
(def vertex-passthrough
"#version 410 core
in vec3 point;
void main()
{
  gl_Position = vec4(point, 1);
}")

(def fragment-blue
"#version 410 core
out vec3 fragColor;
void main()
{
  fragColor = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}")

(def fragment-red
"#version 410 core
out vec3 fragColor;
void main()
{
  fragColor = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}")

(fact "Correct switching between two vertex array objects and shader programs"
  (offscreen-render 160 120
    (let [indices   [0 1 3 2]
          vertices1 [-1.0 -1.0 0.1, 0.5 -1.0 0.1, -1.0 0.5 0.1, 0.5 0.5 0.1]
          vertices2 [-0.5 -0.5 0.2, 1.0 -0.5 0.2, -0.5 1.0 0.2, 1.0 1.0 0.2]
          program1  (make-program :sfsim.render/vertex [vertex-passthrough] :sfsim.render/fragment [fragment-red])
          program2  (make-program :sfsim.render/vertex [vertex-passthrough] :sfsim.render/fragment [fragment-blue])
          vao1      (make-vertex-array-object program1 indices vertices1 ["point" 3])
          vao2      (make-vertex-array-object program2 indices vertices2 ["point" 3])]
      (clear (vec3 0.0 0.0 0.0))
      (use-program program1)
      (render-quads vao1)
      (use-program program2)
      (render-quads vao2)
      (destroy-vertex-array-object vao2)
      (destroy-vertex-array-object vao1)
      (destroy-program program2)
      (destroy-program program1))) => (is-image "test/sfsim/fixtures/render/objects.png" 0.0))
```

On an AMD/ATI card I get the expected result:

[image: AMD/ATI graphics card]

However running the same test suite with NVidia GeForce RTX 2080 and proprietary drivers does not show the first (the red) quad:

[image: NVidia GeForce RTX 2080]

Do you have any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

I added `(println (GL11/glGetError))` in many places and I was getting error 1282. So I disabled all other tests and now it works. I'll enable the other tests one by one and see which one is not closing its OpenGL context propery.